# Validating input of a form in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am trying to validate input to a form before passing it to the server but it doesn't seem to check the input field, and doesn't report an error.
my directive code to create a custom validator:

```
`var QUERY_REGEXP = /[A-Z,a-z,0-9]{1,20}/;
 app.directive('q', function() {
 return {
require: 'ngModel',
link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
  ctrl.$validators.q = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
    if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {

      return true;
    }

    if (QUERY_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  };
  }
 };
});`
```

html for the same:

```
    <div ng-controller="CreditsController">     
    <div style="padding-top:20px" >
    <form name='form' novalidate>
    <b>Enter Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><input id="creditq" ng-model='query1' name='query1' type="text" q />
    <button id="Submit" ng-click='click()' ng-value='search' required>Search</button><br/><br/>
    <span ng-show="form.query1.$error.query1">The value is not valid!</span>
    </form>
    </div>
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing or doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it getting into the $validators.q function at all, or just not displaying the error?

Comment: I got it to work. There was a coding error which was pointed out to me by @bgoscinski. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see few problems here:

- regexp: `/[A-Z,a-z,0-9]{1,20}/` will match **any** string which consists of upper and lower cased letters, digits and a **coma**. `{1,20}` is not going to help here because you didn't specify that it have to *fit* between begin and end of the whole string. I think your regexp should be: `/^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,20}$/`
- According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

  > As with exec() (or in combination with it), test() called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.

  So you have two options: recreate regexp on every validator call or reset `lastIndex` property to `0` on every call.
- Your validator is named `q` so

  `<span ng-show="form.query1.$error.query1">The value is not valid!</span>`

  Will never show because `$error` will never have `query1` property. It will be named `q` as your validator.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the problems I had, it seems to work fine when I type it out in the input field, though I wanted it to validate upon clicking submit so that the value doesn't pass through. Any way I can do this?

Comment: If by _pass through_ you mean that you want your form not to be submitted unless validation succeed you can check `form.$valid` or `form.$invalid` property.